# Starting ImageMagick process on windows server failing with "the specified module could not be found."

Tags: c#, .net, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I'm using ImageMagick to convert PDF files to PNG. Running the process from my Web API project locally works as long as I run Visual Studio as admin. When moving the solution to the server the ImageMagick process fails with the following error

> convert.exe: unable to load module `C:\Program
>   Files\ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_PNG_.dll': The
>   specified module could not be found.

I have both ghostscript and ImageMagick installed as they should be on the server. What could be a cause for this? I can verify that the module does in fact exist on the server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution to this problem in my situation was to set the environment variable for ImageMagick directly in the code where I was calling the process.

```
System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", @"C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16");
```

Apparently even if the environment variable is set on the server, it may not find it due to the runtime being different.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, after a fresh installation of Imagemagick, I got simillar error (unable to load module). What helped was simple:

**Reboot the system**

*It's probably 'cause PATH system variable or something like this has to take effect.*

Comment: Jesus Christ... Used hours on troubleshooting this error, thank you. These errors in imagestick are just way off in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was able to solve this using the portable version so it doesn't have to find anything as it's all embedded on the exe.

Comment: Thank you, portable version works absolutely great in case ImageMagick is called from another application (not just in command line).

Answer (score 0):

If you just installed ImageMagick and you are trying to run this from the command line, you will need to open a new command line window that has the updated %PATH% environment variable.

You could try something with SETX, but opening a new command line window seems a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your Visual Studio or any IDE (Even your command prompts, close and open them again).

System Path not being updated, is causing this error in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Can Imagemagick be used to find libpng? Is it actually installed? Are you calling the ImageMagick convert.exe or the Windows convert.exe?

```
convert.exe -version
```

should show png in the list of delegates?  What are you finding from that command?